# Matrix with same image and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does exists a matrix A for which kernel of A is the same as the image of A?

Answer is True. But I couldn't find the example. I think I saw it from somewhere but I can't find it.  It was 2 by 2 matrix.

Comment: Look for a nonzero matrix such that $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = e_1 e_2^T$. Then $\ker A = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1 \}$, and ${\cal R }(A) = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1 \}$.

Note that since since $\dim {\cal R }(A) + \dim \ker A = n$, the dimension of the domain must be even.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$